# Trunc(sysdate) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, t-sql

What is the equivalent of:

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

...in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: The question is legitimate - the OP wants the equivalent of ORACLE functionality.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recommended:

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

This is another alternative, but it's risky because of casting to a FLOAT.  It's also been demonstrated to not scale performance as well as the DATEADD/DATEDIFF approach.

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I have to do all that just to get TRUNC()?

Comment: This works, but it would be more correct to switch the 2nd and 3rd arguments of DATEADD.  The second argument is the increment, so you're adding 0 to the days returned by DATEDIFF.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) (MSSQL 2008 and later) and either use an appropriate style or use a style that you can then SUBSTRING. I have no idea about the performance compared to the dateadd/datediff solution though.

e.g.

`SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 120), 1, 16)`

Returns:

`2012-01-03 15:30`

Example using group that lists rows created per minute (presupposes a 'created' datetime column):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), created, 120), 1, 16) as [minute]
, COUNT(1) as [per min]
FROM foo
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), created, 120), 1, 16)
```

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2008 or later, just use CONVERT(date,getdate()).  `Date` data type doesn't store time info.

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2022 CTP 2.1, DATETRUNC() is now supported which should line up well with the TRUNC() capability in Oracle.  Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).